# Read a file with root permissions from python script

Tags: python, file, permissions, root

At this time I have some problems with read file permissions (root). I'm trying to open a log file generated by iptables in my system (rsyslogd). So, when I generate that file into /var/log/iptables.log, made by root user (instead my user have all permission granted by sudoers configuration)

I'm using a wraper to open the file (Pygtail), but is the same than open function in python.

```
for line in Pygtail(self.path_source):
    if len(line) > 1:
       print "\n Procesando línea --> " + str(line)
       self.processLine(line)
```

When I execute the script, my terminal show me this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/iptables.log'

Exception IOError: (13, 'Permission denied', '/var/log/iptables.log') in <bound method Pygtail.__del__ of <pygtail.core.Pygtail object at 0x7f2fb8127350>> ignored
```

And iptables.log permissions are:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 0 dic 20 11:27 iptables.log
```

I just want open the file, read all lines and process into my python script. Nothing else.

Any ideas? I'll see some libraries into pip like [oslo.rootwrap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oslo.rootwrap), but I don't understand it very well.

Comment: Can u execute the script as root? (e.g. `sudo`) ?

Comment: Yes, but if there's another possiblity better :( (I just saw something related to SUID but do not know if it will be related.)

Comment: Looks like `Pygtail` might have some additional functionality that is causing the permission problem. Have you tried just reading in the file normally? `print [line for line in open('/var/log/iptables.log').read().splitlines()]`

Comment: @vesche I tried that, but I have the same problem with permissions. I think the solution could be in bit SUID of file (but doesn't work too =( )

Comment: I don't know if this form is dangerous or not, but it works. I just change permissions of the file with `chmod` : `chmod 4644 iptables.log`. But I don't understand why (It's the SUID bit but only works if the 3 octets have read permissions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Consisted that file permissions create by rsyslogd. By default is octet 644, but in my case was wrong (640).

So, I just change that value for /etc/rsyslog.conf in my system and now the new files generated in /var/log/ have the right permissions.

```
$FileCreateMode 0644
```

> fileCreateMode [default 0644] [octalNumber]
>
> Default: 0644
>
> Sets the default fileCreateMode to be used for an action if no
>   explicit one is specified.

[File Output Module rsyslog configuration](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfile.html)

Thanks for your help! =)

PD: Now I have another problem with .offset file generated by pygtail (permissions too) . But that is another problem than not correspond to this question.